# possible to access page after sign out using Forms Authentication in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm using Forms Authentication for user authentication. After login to `default.aspx` page using login credentials and sign out from default.aspx page and redirect to `login.aspx` page. after that if I try to load the page `default.aspx` page by selecting directly from the IE address bar, I could load that page by using previous credentials. Here is the sign out code,

```
protected void Signout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("Logon.aspx");
}
```

Here is the authentication part in web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="All" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Here is the process,

```
1. Login to default page using login credential
2. sign out from default page
3. select the default page directly from address bar.
```

Comment: Have you got anything on your Page_Load ( or master page class ) which enforces the security check?

Comment: see the pageload part of default.aspx,
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Welcome.Text = "Welcome, " + Context.User.Identity.Name;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
        <deny users ="?" />
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This denies the anonymous users from that page (Default.aspx). you can also set the location to an entire folder.

This should be done in we.config file. within the .

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you... not helped this, getting same issue.

Comment: I got the answer from here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629656/prevent-back-option-in-browser-after-logout-from-the-application